# div style height not working

Tags: php, css, html

I need to style the size of a div directly in the html but I have a problem. The div container size only works if I style the height inside a CSS class, otherwise the container won't have any height (even styling it in the div tag instead, what I'm trying to do).

The width and height are taken from the image, and I don't know any other way to do this;

```
list($width, $height) = getimagesize('dir/to/img.jpg');
echo $width . $height; //WORKING

// resizing the img...
// the resizing script have max width and height
$img_width = 'width="' . $width . '"';
$img_height = 'height="' . $height . '"';

<div class="img_container" ' . $img_width . ' ' . $img_height . '>
    <img src="'. $img_dir . '" class="img"/>
</div>

// the html output is ok but maybe it's not overwriting the css
```

This is the css class I'm using for the container:

```
.img_container {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    min-height: 50px;
    max-height: auto;
}
.img {
    height: auto;
    display: block;
}
```

If I remove the height from `.img_container`, the div won't have any height (and the image is not shown, but the div has the width and height).

So what I want is the div to have the same width and height as the image does.

Comment: firstly, what happen when you insert semicolon after `height: auto`?

Comment: What does the html look like and do you have any additional css (like absolute positioning...) for the images?

Comment: You're just not setting the height of the div at all. Just outputting some pixel values without even any attributes for the div tag (as you do it) does not do anything. Perhaps re-visit a HTML/CSS guide of your choice?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote those two options. Yes, I have position: absolute in the image and relative in the container.

Comment: I didn't say it, the attributes are already in the variables. I just edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inline styles should overwrite (have higher priority than) external CSS, but you haven't set the width and height properly. You should use the `style` attribute like this;

```
<div class="img_container" style="width: <?php echo $width; ?>px; height: <?php echo $height; ?>px;">
```

You also needed to re-enter PHP parsing to use PHP variables (with the `<?php ?>` tags as above).

Additionally, you have an error in your CSS as you haven't put a semicolon (`;`) at the end of your `img` rules.

Comment: Sorry, I shoul've said that. The variables contains it already: $img_width = 'width="' . $width . '"';

Comment: Ah yes. Using `width=` and `height=` aren't going to overwrite the CSS, and are depreciated.

Comment: The style="width/height" will work? Or it's the same?

Comment: I've updated my answer. You should just use the raw numbers from the `getimagesize` function, and put into the `style=` parameter.

Comment: Thank you, the problem was I didn't write "px": $img_width = 'width: ' . $width . 'px;'; But now it's working!

Answer (score 0):

I found height:auto worked for me in getting the contents within the div.